# Unable to Upload .jar file in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a .jar file to Amazon S3 in the AWS Console.
The error msg said:
Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReaderSync': The requested file could not be read, typically due to permission problems that have occurred after a reference to a file was acquired.

It should get uploaded in S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried uploading jar file to s3 and it is working as expected.To debug more on the error try to upload file with aws s3 cli command.If you jar is bigger in size you can also use multipart file upload.

[AWS s3 multipart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpu-upload-object.html)

[Screenshot of JAR file upload to s3 console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ze5HU.png)

Answer (score -1):

This error message usually occurs when the .jar file you're trying to upload doesn't have the necessary permissions or is locked by another process.

Try the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Make sure that the .jar file is not open or in use by another process.
2. Check that the file permissions are set to allow read and write access.
3. If the file is located on a network drive, try copying it to your local machine and then uploading it to S3.
4. If the issue persists, try restarting your computer and trying the upload again.
5. If the problem still persists, it may be worth checking the AWS S3 documentation or reaching out to AWS Support for further assistance.